# Is it possible to place page within another page?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobiles 1.4.2
Is it possible to place a page within another page before closing first page.

### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>header</h1>
</div>
 <div data-role="content">
   <a href="#page2">Go to Page Two</a>
   contents</div>
 <div data-role="page" id="page2">
 <div data-role="header">
 <h1>header2</h1>

 </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, you can't. Nothing can prevent you but this "page" will never work as regular page. All pages must be part of a page container which is **body**.

On the other hand, inner pages were possible before with some 3rd party plugins but they were not updated since jQuery Mobile 1.0.

Comment: Thanq.I have one more question.Plz go through this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988222/how-to-get-id-from-one-page-to-other-page.In this i have to refer id from pageone to page2

Comment: I already gave you an answer, take a look and tell me if you need more information.