# How to get id from one page to other page?

Tags: php, jquery, string, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobiles 1.4.2

I have to refer id from one page to other page.

### html

```
     <div data-role="page">
     <div data-role="header">
            hello</div>
     <div data-role="content">

     <a href="#freeadd" id="ofrecer"  data-role="button" data-mini="true">Ofrezco en Venta</a>
       <a href="#freeadd" id="ofrecer" class="aliq" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Ofrezco en Alquiler</a>
        <a id="busco" href="#freeadd" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Buscar</a>

         </div>

          </div>


          <div data-role="page" id="freeadd">
         <div data-role="header">
          display id
           </div>
                 </div>
```

In next page i want to display the heading depending on the id(instead of display id).Please any one help me..

Comment: what is your problem exactly? You want to transfer data from one page to another with php?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Its multipage programing.I have used two pages(data-role="page" two times) and I have given id of second page in first page.

Comment: @user3350169 so you say that you are missing lots of important information in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several solutions exist:

**Solution 1:**

You can pass values with changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

And read them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

#### Example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Test</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you can create a persistent javascript object for a storage purpose. As long ajax is used for page loading (and page is not reloaded in any way) that object will stay active.

```
var storeObject = {
    firstname : '',
    lastname : ''
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

**Solution 3:**

You can also access data from the previous page like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index',function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

**prevPage** object holds a complete previous page.

**Solution 4:**

As a last solution we have a nifty HTML implementation of localStorage. It only works with HTML5 browsers (including Android and iOS browsers) but all stored data is persistent through page refresh.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
    localStorage.lastname="Gaic";            
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/

Find more about them **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)**.

Comment: Its showing alert box in my page but its not displaying "Dragan Gaic" I mean its not displaying value

Comment: Do you think I'm a psychic? :) I can't see your code thus I can't help you. You should accept this answer because I gave you several solutions to your question. Then open another one and show me your code there, I will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Where is link to another page? I see only links to specific page part.

But basically you just pass that id as url param: `www.example.com?id=45`

Than in php:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) { // will check if argument exists and check if it's not === 0
   $title = $db->getTitleById((int) $_GET['id']);
} 

if (empty($title)){ // Will check if there was id param passed and entry was found in DB
   $title = 'Some default title';
}
```